# Ajax: getting datas from json file every 10minutes and draw it in Googles globe API

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, google-api

I recently downloaded [Armsglobe](https://armsglobe.chromeexperiments.com/) (Googles globe API to draw lines in countries using their country name). but their original code is written without getting the json datas every **x**-minutes.

so i was hoping if you could help me how i can achieve that without breaking the entire appearance, which i already did after i tried to do a simple `setTimeout()` function in *dataloading.js* as follows:

```
function loadContentData(callback){ 
  function request_xhr() {
    var filePath = "categories/All3.json";
    filePath = encodeURI( filePath );

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open( 'GET', filePath, true );      
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ( xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200 ) {
            timeBins = JSON.parse( xhr.responseText ).timeBins;

            // console.log(timeBins);

            maxValue = 0;
            // console.log(timeBins);

            startTime = timeBins[0].t;
            endTime = timeBins[timeBins.length-1].t;
            timeLength = endTime - startTime;                                                                       

            if(callback)
                callback();             
            // console.log("finished read data file");      
        }
    };
    xhr.send( null );   
  }
 request_xhr();
 setTimeout(request_xhr, 20000);

}
```

^ this works and actually gets the json file every given minute, but it doesnt draw it, or show it anyhow. infact, it contradicts with the 3D globe and it becomes immovable and corrupts immediately. i dont know what exactly is making it like this, but i think the browser is caching it and showing the cached datas instead of the new datas.

i know my ways are a bit odd and inappropriate, i just couldn't see other ways. any new idea or way is welcomed! please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to ensure you draw it only after you receive the data. By calling the function inside the call back you are ensuring the next call be made only after you render first one

```
function loadContentData(callback){ 
  var self = this;
  function request_xhr() {
    var filePath = "categories/All3.json";
    filePath = encodeURI( filePath );

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open( 'GET', filePath, true );      
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ( xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200 ) {
            timeBins = JSON.parse( xhr.responseText ).timeBins;

            // console.log(timeBins);

            maxValue = 0;
            // console.log(timeBins);

            startTime = timeBins[0].t;
            endTime = timeBins[timeBins.length-1].t;
            timeLength = endTime - startTime;                                                                       

            if(callback)
                callback();             
            // console.log("finished read data file");                  
        self.request_xhr();
       }
    };
    xhr.send( null );   
  }
 request_xhr();

}
```

Comment: i got your point, but its still just messing up after getting the new data. is there any way that i can upload it and show you what it looks like after getting the new data? might be hard to express what i mean by "messing up"

Comment: Sure, please use https://jsfiddle.net or add the rest of the code along with error message/screen-shot to your question

Comment: There are a lot of other .js,imgs,htmls and its kinda hard to write it once in jsfiddle.net so i just uploade the 3MB zipped in here: https://ufile.io/a6414 Thank you for taking the time!!